# Can not print in Text area from same class?

Tags: java, textarea

I want to print in the text area named `arena`. I am calling the `append` method from the same class with no luck so far. How to print a string in a text area??

```
public class Chat_window extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

    public static DataInputStream in = null;
    public static PrintStream out = null;
    private static Socket cs = null;
    private static BufferedReader zz;
    private static boolean alive = true;

    public Chat_window() {    
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
          java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Chat_window w=new Chat_window();
                w.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
          try {
            cs = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
            out = new PrintStream(cs.getOutputStream());
            zz = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            in = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        if (cs != null && out != null && in != null) {
            try {
                new Thread(new Chat_window()).start();
                while (alive) {
                    out.println(zz.readLine().trim());                 
                }
                out.close();
                in.close();
                cs.close();
            } catch (Exception error) {
                System.out.println(error);

            }
        }      
    }
   @Override

    public void run() {      
        try {
            while ((m = in.readLine()) != null) {             
                **arena.append(m);**             //This line doesnt work             
                System.out.println(m);               
            }         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }    
    }

    // Variables declaration                      
    private java.awt.TextArea arena;

    private java.awt.TextArea textArea2;
    private java.awt.TextArea usrchat;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: I know that it is about creating duplicate text area where one is not visible but how to make it print on main text area???

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean ?

Comment: That line doesnt print anything in text area

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace it with `arena.setText(arena.getText()+"\n"+m);`

Or
`arena.setText(arena.getText()+m);`
If you don't want to add a new line in between :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but It doesn't work. text area only displays if u select text area and press any key. Only last line is displayed. I want to print it same way as it does it on console.